# How insecure is this?

Tags: django, security, passwords

Looking for feedback. I am building a django app where users are given randomly generated passwords.

Currently, the password is being generated using the make_random_password() function in django auth.

However, early feedback is that the emails are too hard to remember (even though the users can change them).

This is a closed (invite only) app, but it lives on the internet. with about 600 users total. I had a solution that I feel is is somewhat insecure, but I wanted to run it by SO users, as it solves the feedback issue

In my settings.py file, I have created two lists, one contains about 20 car names, the other about 40 verbs (which are capitalized).

I was going randomly select one from each list, join them together and then append a few random chars to the end.

All passwords would be at least 9 chars long and when saved are hashed using django's set_password() function

The biggest issue I see is that if someone were to gain access to the SFTP server they would then have access to my code AND hence a template for cracking the pwords.

BUT they would also have db access etc, so is it really a  concern?

Comment: I am reserving the right to say, no, the random generated pword is the way to go - one always has the "security" trump card.

Comment: make a "click here to change your password" link on the email

Comment: That's true, but that's like the old saying that anything can be done if you say that it fixes a "health and safety" issue.  For a closed app, I'd say that such a password system is okay.  I wouldn't worry about someone gaining access to the FTP server - that's the case for pretty much any web app, and if someone did that, they'd have the DB password and could do anything!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always assume that the attacker has access to your password generation scheme. Basing your security on the assumption that he doesn't is trusting security through obscurity. Obscurity can give a nice security bonus but you should never rely on it.

You must assume the attacker knows the content of both lists. For example he can simply register about 40 times, and then knows a significant part of them.

Your car-names combined with the verbs have about 9.6(=log2(20)+log2(40)) bits of entropy. Corresponds to about 2 random characters. That's very low.

Comment: Very good points. The 40 registration scenario won't happen, however as the site is heavily managed. Before the password is even generated, the user must pre register their email and their identity must be verified offline.

Answer (score 3):

Can you force a password change the first time a user logs in? Or, if all your users have already been logged in, force a password change the next log in? That way, you can keep the more secure passwords and users can't complain about the randomly generated password being hard to remember because they have to change them to something they do remember.

Answer (score 3):

How about using an OpenID system, so they don't have to remember yet another password. There's some Django integration on the interwebs. The downside is that you'll need to know their OpenID in order to add them to the auth DB before you send out the invites...

Answer (score 1):

The Concept of doing a random password generation as far as you have a flag stating which random password generation pattern used for generating the password as you need to check the password in later sign ins.. are you doing that? If yes then add a salting pattern to make it secure and finally a hash of the overall salt generated will be more safe. Try this ..